# can we write something just before the a relative clause which refers to the whole sentence?

Tags: relative-clauses

Sentence: "They may play games or sports, or enjoy simply sitting and chatting together, activities which are far healthier than sitting alone hunched over a screen."

Do we have to write the sentence without "activities" (,which are healthier....) ?

Also, is using such a thing like "activities" possible ? Most of the relative clauses referring to the whole sentence have same structure ",which is/are bla bla". Thats why I confused

Comment: The sentence is correct and natural with or without "activities".

Comment: I disagree with @gotube and the answer below. The sentence has an error of parallelism in the series: the first two conjuncts ("games" and "sports") are nouns while the third ("simply sit and chat together") is a verb phrase. That makes it hard to understand how the last part ("activities which are . . .") relates to the earlier parts. Did you write this yourself or find it somewhere? If you found it, then you must [cite the source](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/so-you-found-a-sentence-or-phrase-why-you-should-cite-your-source).

Comment: (It's actually possible that "games" and "sports" are conjuncts in their own series, which is part of a larger series that includes the conjuncts "play games, sports" and "simply sit and chat together". However, it is unusual for a series with only two conjuncts to use a comma-separator and sounds very unnatural here.)

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Good catch. The sentence was not grammatical. The error doesn't seem to affect the question -- other than distracting attention from it -- so I've just edited it. I think the question still has the same intent, and now my comment and Astralbee's answer are correct.

Comment: @gotube Thanks! I made one more small edit, to use the gerunds "sitting" and "chatting", so that we have nominals for "activities" to be in apposition to (or, if "activities" is removed, for the relative pronoun "which" to refer to).

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is grammatically sound with or without the word 'activities', but it is far better with it included as it removes ambiguity.

You have a list of activities separated by commas:

- games
- sports
- sit and chat together

As the last activity is actually two things (sitting *and* chatting) it could sound like your next clause is just describing those two things as 'healthier'. By including the word 'activities' it makes it clear that you are referring to all the previously listed activities.

Comment: +1 I've edited the original sentence because I'm pretty sure it was a mistake, and distracted from the actual question about "activities". You may way to amend your answer -- or revert my edit for that matter.